# How to access route object in Vue prototype?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

How to access $route object, similar to this.$route, in a custom Vue prototype?

```
//main.js
Vue.prototype['$notify'] = params => {
    //console.log('this', this) undefined
    console.log('Vue.prototype', Vue.prototype)
    /* console shows among other valid properties:
$route: [Exception: TypeError: Cannot read property '_route' of undefined at Object.get (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.esm.js:1221:52) at Object.invokeGetter (<anonymous>:2:14)]
$router: [Exception: TypeError: Cannot read property '_router' of undefined at Object.get (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue-router/dist
    */

//this throws error: Vue.prototype.$route
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrow function isn't a shortcut for regular function, that it uses lexical `this` instead of dynamic `this` is one of the differences.

In case the method should access Vue instance, it should be:

```
Vue.prototype['$notify'] = function (params) {
  console.log(this.$route);
  ...
};
```

Comment: @Marius If you did everything correctly, it should work. E.g. https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-routing-example-smjwd

Comment: Thanks Estus, it does work now. Maybe a fresh day helped :)